# Issues making this button clickable inside it's border

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues making this button clickable inside its border. Am i missing something? my code is
below or in the link provided. if you hover above and below the buttons, then you see the whole
section is clickable. I know if i change the position to absolute it will solve this but it just makes
the whole page in to a mess, if there is a way to keep the position relative, then i would prefer this.
any advice would be very grateful, as I'm just a beginner.
Sorry if my code is a mess. Also first post on Stack overflow so im not sure how to post properly.

https://codepen.io/sion-morris/pen/JjKjZaY

```
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay h1 {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  mix-blend-mode:multiply;
  border: 5px black solid;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: Dancing Script, cursive;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: 2s;
  padding: 10px;

}
.overlay h1:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: transparent;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: Dancing Script, cursive;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 20px;
}
.overlay h1:last-child:hover {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

.buttoncontainer{
  display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
.button {
  margin-top: 400px;
}
```

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="buttoncontainer">
            <a a href="portfolio.html">
              <div class="overlay button">
                <h1>Portfolio</h1>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a a href="contact.html">
              <div class="overlay button">
                <h1>Contact</h1>
              </div>
            </a>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Here is snippet:

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay h1 {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  mix-blend-mode:multiply;
  border: 5px black solid;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: Dancing Script, cursive;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: 2s;
  padding: 10px;

}
.overlay h1:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: transparent;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: Dancing Script, cursive;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 20px;
}
.overlay h1:last-child:hover {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

.buttoncontainer{
  display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
.button {
  margin-top: 400px;
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="buttoncontainer">
            <a a href="#">
              <div class="overlay button">
                <h1>Portfolio</h1>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a a href="#">
              <div class="overlay button">
                <h1>Contact</h1>
              </div>
            </a>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: <https://codepen.io/sion-morris/pen/JjKjZaY>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **margins** are the issue here.

You have `margin-top: 100px` on the `.button` which is inside the `a`. So the link is stretched out and includes the whole margin. Margin in yellow below.

[image]

You're also using `h1` which is inline so its margins will stretch outside its box.

[image]

A solution is to remove the margin from `.button` and `h1` and add margin to `.buttoncontainer a` to keep the space above.

```
.button {
}
.buttoncontainer a {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.overlay h1 {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  border: 5px black solid;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: Dancing Script, cursive;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: 2s;
  padding: 10px;
}

.overlay h1:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: transparent;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: Dancing Script, cursive;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 20px;
}

.overlay h1:last-child:hover {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

.buttoncontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.buttoncontainer a {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttoncontainer">
  <a href="portfolio.html">
    <div class="overlay button">
      <h1>Portfolio</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="contact.html">
    <div class="overlay button">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've placed a `<div>` with a `margin-top:100px;` inside your anchor tag, which works in HTML5 but isn't considered good practice, and here it leads to your margin stretching the button.

Switching them around leads to your desired result:

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay h1 {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  mix-blend-mode:multiply;
  border: 5px black solid;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: Dancing Script, cursive;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: 2s;
  padding: 10px;

}
.overlay h1:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: transparent;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: Dancing Script, cursive;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 20px;
}
.overlay h1:last-child:hover {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

.buttoncontainer{
  display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

.button{
  margin-top:100px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="buttoncontainer">
            <div class="button">
              <a href="portfolio.html" class="overlay">
                <h1>Portfolio</h1>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
              <a href="contact.html" class="overlay button">
                <h1>Contact</h1>
              </a>
            </div>
      </div>
```

Note that you can probably omit the button class entirely and place the margin inside your `buttonContainer` class. (As mentioned by Zac before me)